# 'I don't remember saying that' vs 'I don't remember having said that'

Tags: grammar

*Having said that* is a really well-known phrase used to mean *however*, but is it OK to say

> I don't remember **having said** that

instead of saying

> I don't remember **saying** that.

What is this grammar topic named?

Comment: What do you mean by “grammar topic”? Are you looking for the term *present perfect*, which is the name of the tense?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum The present perfect structure as far as I know is Have+past participle, I have never seen it with "having" I thought this would be called something like perfect participle or something like that

Comment: It's fine. There's little difference between the two; essentially just two slightly different ways of saying the same thing, though the version with "having" does tend to convey a sense of current relevance.

Comment: "Having said that" only means "however" when it's used as a conjunction to relate two statements. Your use of the phrase in the first example is unrelated to this, it's just the ordinary past perfect.

Comment: I don't believe the more complex verb form *actually* carries any nuance of difference. More specifically, I don't believe that even the most careful writer/speaker would consciously *choose* the more complex ([**much** less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remember+saying+that%2Cremember+having+said+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)) form in the expectation / hope that his audience / readers would actually *understand* his intended distinction. Any supposed semantic difference is just wishful thinking on the part of language mavens.

Comment: "saying that" and "having said that" are both **gerund** phrases. The difference is "having said" has the perfect aspect. They're not present, unlike what @Paul's saying; that would be "*I have* said" (simple) or "*I have been* saying" (continuous).

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to your question but if you add more to the sentence it will mean something different:  "I don't remember saying that when he left" and "I don't remember having said that when he left" suggest totally different timelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- On Monday, I made a speech, in which I said “Ice is cool”.
- On Tuesday, I watched a recording of the speech, and remembered saying “Ice is cool”.
- On Wednesday, I crossed the river Lima, and lost all memory of Monday.
- On Thursday, I had no recollection of saying “Ice is cool”: I did not remember saying it. However, I remembered watching the recording on Tuesday, and that I *had* said “Ice is cool”: I remembered having said it.
- On Friday, I accidentally forgot the whole past week.
- On Saturday, I re-discovered the recording. While I became aware that I must have said “Ice is cool”, I neither remembered saying it *or* having said it.

There is a subtle difference between remembering an event, and remembering that the event has occurred: the latter includes indirect recollection as well. However, situations where the distinction is relevant are rare, so “I remember saying that” and “I remember having said that” are plesionymous. A difference in meaning is unlikely to be perceived unless the two are contrasted, such as: explicitly, in the sentence

> I don't remember *saying* it, but I remember having *said* it.

(note: the emphasis is meaningful); or if the speaker is known to be pedantic about such things, such that their choice of words is conspicuous.

Another example would be “I remember saying that” and “I remember when I said that”: the meanings might diverge if the speaker is plural, a time traveller, or was [completely out of it](https://xkcd.com/861/) at the time, but an English speaker is unlikely to perceive any of these meanings without further context. (“When I said that” might also refer to the wider events surrounding / resulting from the (presumably notable) utterance: this meaning is likely to be understood with minimal context.)

Comment: *On Thursday, I had no recollection of saying “Ice is cool”: I **did not remember saying it**. However, I remembered watching the recording on Tuesday, and that I had said “Ice is cool”: I **remembered having said it**.* That doesn't look like an "explanation" to me - it looks more like an "oxymoron". Are you suggesting that there would be a difference (in either *meaning* or "idiomacy") if those two constructions were swapped? I can't see what difference it would make.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the quoted passage, the bit before each colon is a special case of the bit after the colon. It's the difference between "I remember when I said it" and "I remember when it was necessarily the case that I said it".

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say. I just don't accept that many if any native anglophones would either intend or understand any such semantic distinction.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 you may be grammatically correct, but as FumbleFingers says almost no-one that you meet outside of an English Professor's office would *actually* interpret a distinction.

Comment: @Brondahl In ordinary speech, no, but lots of things in English are like that: synonymous until somebody emphasises the distinction. ”I don't remember _saying_ it, but I remember having _said_ it.” seems like perfectly valid (and meaningful) spoken English to me.

Comment: Ooh .... eesh ... yeah, just about :D. Fair enough, I think you've sold me. But I think that (explicitly highlighting a distinction to make a point) is a crucial scenario to emphasise in your answer.

Comment: i.e. I think without that point, I find the answer to be misleading - (to me) it currently implies that the average English-user would actively understand a difference even without that "making a point" context.... Which I disagree with.

Comment: @Brondahl Is this better?

Comment: Yep, I'm very sold on this answer now :D +1

Comment: ..the river Lethe, I take it? ;)

Answer (score 7):

*I don’t remember having said that* is perfectly idiomatic. Prescriptivists would likely quibble about its tense: “What you **say** you don’t remember is ever occupying the state earlier than which you said that.” But I wouldn’t recommend concerning yourself about it.

It **is** true, of course, that *I don’t remember saying that* gets it done more simply and cleanly.

Comment: I don't know if I am an especially 'careful' native speaker, but I think I might say **either** that I don't remember doing or saying something **or** that I am not aware of having done or said it. Remembering _having done_ something is different from remembering _doing_ it.

Comment: @Paul Tanenbaum What does than which mean? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: It’s “earlier than which.” See @MichaelHarvey’s comment. For the difference between your two, compare to this: Suppose that in the midst of eating a meal you suddenly and instantly passed out, to wake up six hours later. In that example, if someone asked immediately on your reviving to describe your memories, you might report that you remembered **eating** (because you were conscious while you ate), but you did not remember **having eaten** (because, due to your fainting, your had no recollection of any point after you were eating, your most recent memory was of eating).

Comment: If I remember killing my mother-in-law, I recall getting the gun out, pulling the trigger, the bang the gun made. Remembering having killed her involves the guilt (or lack of it), my wife's screams, the arrival of the police, the newspaper headlines, the start of my jail sentence, etc.

Answer (score 6):

These two phrases have nuanced differences, but in actual practical contexts the difference is *de minimis*.

> I don't remember saying that.
>
> I don't remember having said that.

The first focuses on the *act of saying*, on the speech-act itself. The second broadens the focus to include not only the speech-act but also its immediate aftermath: the "saying" resulted in a statement made on an occasion.

To paraphrase those sentences in a manner that *exaggerates* the nuanced difference:

> I don't remember those words coming out of my mouth.
>
> I don't remember such a statement uttered by me and being present after making the statement.

I understand **I don't remember having said that** to be a more definite denial in that **having said** includes by implication a *context* in which the utterance took place. The speaker remembers the context and remembers that he did not make such a statement.

These are *aspect* differences.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible to be certain you said something but not remember exactly when or where, so you might remember having said it, but not remember saying it.